# Reason to stay on a doomed spaceship

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, spaceships, explosions, antimatter

For plot reasons, the captain must stay on the ship while his crew (including his wife) get in escape pods and leave. Unfortunately we haven't found a satisfying reason for this yet.

What engine or ship design flaw or cultural/behavioural convention could force someone to abandon loved ones and their own life in an advanced, "enlightened" and space-faring human society beyond "Cap must go down with the ship"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79857/discussion-on-question-by-joda-reason-to-stay-on-a-doomed-spaceship).

Comment: As it stands the question lacks criteria that would allow an answer to be considered better than any other answer.  Until some criteria are given this is still really broad or POB.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Its an interesting question but per my comment above it lacks detail that would make one answer superior to any other answer.  If you can add some details we can get the question re-opened.  As it stands this should remain closed.  Check out the [help] and [tour] for a little more info on the site.

Comment: @James cheers bud, I'll do better next time!

Answer (score 3):

Because the Captain is supposed to stay on the ship, during a crisis that will put the ship in peril, at the cost of his life. It's not 'meh' at all, a less brave and dutiful captain would be a coward.

Comment: Any number of reasons connected to that as well - keeping the ship on course as long as possible to avoid being a danger to other ships, or as seen in a couple works of sci-fi, using the ship as a weapon in a way that couldn't be done by an auto-pilot.